# Generalize implicit function in scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm new to Scala and am having some trouble wrapping my mind around implicit functions.

Say I have an implicit function that turns `Strings` into `Option[String]` which is written

`implicit def stringToOption(s: String): Option[String] = if(s.isEmpty) { None } else { Some(s) }`

Then I have an XML tree that either could or could not have an attribute `<thing>`

I also have 2 classes which use this implicit function like such:

```
case class ClassA(field: Option[String])

object ClassA {

    implicit val decoder(nodeSeq: NodeSeq) =>
      ClassA(field = nodeSeq \@ "thing")
}
```

And

```
case class ClassB(field: Option[String])

object ClassB {

    implicit val decoder(nodeSeq: NodeSeq) =>
      ClassB(field = nodeSeq \@ "thing")
}
```

Is there a way to store the implicit function such that both of these separate classes will know to turn the `String` into `Option[String]` in both?

Ordinarily, I would stick in `stringToOption` into one of the classes like:

```
case class ClassB(field: Option[String])

object ClassB {

    implicit def stringToOption(s: String): Option[String] = if(s.isempty) {None} else {Some(s)}

    implicit val decoder(nodeSeq: NodeSeq) =>
      ClassB(field = nodeSeq \@ "thing")
}
```

But, I would like to stick it somewhere else so that it's available for both classes and I don't need to rewrite it as such in both. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where would you use `stringToOption`?

Comment: Edited the question to hopefully explain better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit functions are considered a bad practice as they make code harder to follow and make mistakes easier.  They currently require a language import to use without warnings and [there is discussion to potentially heavily restrict them](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/2060).

That said, it is possible to do what you ask.
Define your implicit function in an object somewhere then import it where you need it.

```
object DangerousImplicits {
  implicit def stringToOption(s: String): Option[String] = if(s.isempty) {None} else {Some(s)}
}
```

Now you can import this into whatever place you want this implicit conversion.  (I would recommend importing within a method to minimize the scope of the import)

```
import DangerousImplicits.stringToOption
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reference confirming possible removal of implicit conversion from future versions of Scala?

Comment: @Haspemulator Added a link the relevant PR discussion.